# Spring Data Neo4j: Converter of object to string works, but object to long is not executed

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a really strange issue with converting from domain objects to those Neo4j can natively store as property value. As a test case I use Joda's DateTime. A object of that type can be converted to a String or Long quite easily.

The conversion from DateTime to String works flawlessly with this code:

```
public class DateTimeToStringConverter implements Converter<DateTime, String> {

  @Override
  public String convert(DateTime source) {
    return source.toDateTimeISO().toString();
  }

}
```

The property shows up in the node:

```
Node[1] {
  '__type__' = '...', 
  'entityEditedAt' = '2012-12-28T12:32:50.308+01:00', 
  'entityCreatedAt' = '2012-12-28T12:32:50.297+01:00',
  ...
}
```

However if I like to save the DateTime as Long (useful to sort by time in Cypher), it does not work at all. Here is my converter:

```
public class DateTimeToLongConverter implements Converter<DateTime, Long> {

  @Override
  public Long convert(DateTime source) {
      return source.toDateTimeISO().getMillis();
  }

}
```

The property is not saved on the node. Thus it is missing completely. No exception is thrown. It seems like the conversion code is not called at all.

The converters are hooked to Spring Data using code based configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService() {
    Set converters = Sets.newHashSet();

    // These work!
    converters.add(new DateTimeToStringConverter());
    converters.add(new StringToDateTimeConverter());

    // These don't :-(
    //converters.add(new DateTimeToLongConverter());
    //converters.add(new LongToDateTimeConverter());

    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    bean.setConverters(converters);
    return bean;
}
```

Any clues? I'm quite lost here, as it should work in my opinion...

**Edit**
I found following text in the [Spring Data Neo4j documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#d5e825):

> All fields convertible to a String using the Spring conversion services will be stored as a string.

Does this mean, that only conversions to string are supported? This seems rather limiting.

Answer (score 4):

Tell SDN that you want to store your joda DateTime property as a long with:

```java
@NodeEntity
public class MyEntity {
    ...
    @GraphProperty(propertyType = Long.class)
    private DateTime timestamp;
    ....
}
```

Then your registered DateTimeToLongConverter will kick in.

Comment: Ah cool. However it seems to be usable with version 2.1.M1 according to this post http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123802-Spring-Data-Neo4j-2-1-0-M1-Released. I will try the new version.